# Check if GTK window has keyboard and mouse focus window C++

Tags: c++, gtk

Is there a GTK3 function that detects if a window has focus? I am currently using the following code:

```
#include <gtk/gtk.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
GtkWidget *LinuxWindow;
static void buttonMessage(GtkWidget *widget, gpointer data)
{
  g_print("Yay, you clicked me!\n");
}
int main() {
  GtkWidget *Box, *Button;
  int argC = 0;
  char **argV;
  // Setup the window and fixed grid
  gtk_init(&argC, &argV);
  LinuxWindow = gtk_window_new(GTK_WINDOW_TOPLEVEL);
  Box = gtk_fixed_new();
  // Set the title
  gtk_window_set_title(GTK_WINDOW(LinuxWindow), "Title");
  // Setup the window events
  gtk_widget_show_all(LinuxWindow);
  g_signal_connect(G_OBJECT(LinuxWindow), "destroy", G_CALLBACK(gtk_main_quit),
                   NULL);
  // Add controls
  Button = gtk_button_new_with_label("Click Me!");
  g_signal_connect(Button, "clicked", G_CALLBACK(buttonMessage), NULL);
  gtk_fixed_put(GTK_FIXED(Box), Button, 20, 20);
  gtk_fixed_move(GTK_FIXED(Box), Button, 20, 20);
  gtk_widget_set_size_request(Button, 30, 100);
  gtk_container_add(GTK_CONTAINER(LinuxWindow), Box);
  gtk_widget_show_all(LinuxWindow);
  // Create a dialog
  GtkWidget *dialog;
  dialog = gtk_message_dialog_new(
      GTK_WINDOW(LinuxWindow), GTK_DIALOG_DESTROY_WITH_PARENT,
      GTK_MESSAGE_INFO, GTK_BUTTONS_OK, "Hello and welcome to my GTK GUI...", NULL);
  gint ret = gtk_dialog_run(GTK_DIALOG(dialog));
  gtk_widget_destroy(GTK_WIDGET(dialog));
  printf("%i", ret);
  // Add the fixed grid and go the to the main window loop

  gtk_main();

  return 0;
}
```

I am compiling it using

```
g++ -std=c++17 -m64 -o gtkTest myGtkApp.cpp -lX11 `pkg-config --cflags gtk+-3.0` `pkg-config --libs gtk+-3.0`
```

I want to detect if the window is focused and print it to the console.

Comment: Does it need to be done using GTK. Found a way to do it for linux: https://superuser.com/questions/382616/detecting-currently-active-window and there are lots of ways to do it on windows

Comment: I would prefer if it's done using GTK but if there is another way that works with c++ that would be fine too

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a function: [gtk_widget_is_focus ()](https://developer-old.gnome.org/gtk3/unstable/GtkWidget.html#gtk-widget-is-focus).

You need to assure parents have the "has-focus" property set.
Doc. excerpt:

`gtk_widget_is_focus (GtkWidget *widget);`

> Determines if the widget is the focus widget within its toplevel. (This does not mean that the “has-focus” property is necessarily set; “has-focus” will only be set if the toplevel widget additionally has the global input focus.)

If you want to receive an event when the window is focused then register a callback for the `enter-notify-event` ([signal](https://developer-old.gnome.org/gtk3/unstable/GtkWidget.html#GtkWidget-enter-notify-event))

In the linked doc. there is a section just three points after `enter-notify-event` that is what you want:

> The “focus” signal

Sorry, I should have to mention this event the first time.

---

Edit for new links from [docs.gtk.org](https://docs.gtk.org/):

- [gtk_widget_is_focus ()](https://docs.gtk.org/gtk3/method.Widget.is_focus.html)
- [enter-notify-event](https://docs.gtk.org/gtk3/signal.Widget.enter-notify-event.html)

Comment: I tried the `gtk_widget_is_focus ()` but it only returned 0 and the `enter-notify-event` signal looks like a mouse enter event but not a focus event.

Comment: thanks for the updated answer but how do I set the `has-focus` property?

Comment: @caelras You may read about properties in the [docs](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/ch01s04.html#id-1.2.3.12.12)

Comment: @caelras [Check this Videos](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLN_MPJUQgPVpMFxuUlk5F-ZPvzXeyw1C0) to see how Gtk Properties works.